# Taking characters and integers

Tags: c++, xcode

I've come across a small problem in C++, I'm sure someone can find a solution.

Say if you wanted to make a program that took someone's postal code. Their postal code would consist of letters and numbers.

How would you do this? What type would you use? Or am I missing another function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a `std::string`, somehting like:

```
std::string postal_code = "W10 4RT";
```

Then you could check it with a regular expression like `"[A-Z][0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}[A-Z]"`

Answer (score 0):

char[] or std::string may take chars. So characters and integers can be stored